Delayed server responses when logged in on one browser (any browser!) for a while
This issue sounds kind of ridiculous, but I’ve pinned it down as best I can and ruled out anything obvious.
When I’ve been logged in as admin and working on my site in a browser for a while (“a while” is variable, but maybe half an hour to a few hours), it starts to get extremely slow to load any public or admin page. Using developer tools I can see that the slowdown is caused by huge delays in “waiting for server response” – up to 60s for even small and simple resources. This means a single page can end up taking several minutes to load, and sometimes the browser gives up entirely and times it out.
But these server delays are localised to my current login. I can fix the delay locally by:

Switching to a different browser. (Note: this issue is not specific to a particular browser. If I use firefox for a while it slows down and switching to chrome speeds back up again. If I use chrome for a while it slows down and switching to firefox speeds back up again.)

Clearing my browser cache and history.

Logging in again in an incognito window.

Switching to a different user account on my device.

Giving up for a while and coming back later (without logging out or anything else in between).


Here’s a recording that shows the homepage taking over two minutes to load in chrome, then immediately switching to a firefox window and loading the same page in a few seconds. (Note again, this issue is not specific to chrome, it is specific to whichever browser I have been logged in on and using). https://streamable.com/qadvcy
Things I’ve ruled out:

The slowdown is not an overall server performance issue. If I do a lighthouse report of the public homepage during a slowdown it gives normal results.

I’ve deactivated all plugins with no change.

I’ve enabled and disabled bluehost’s server-side caching with no change.

The issue has been going on for a few months, across various wordpress and plugin updates, but it’s taken me a while to pin it down.


And an additional factor: I have two separate wordpress installs on the same shared hosting, one as a subdomain of the other. They both display this same issue. And I think (but am not 100% certain yet) that a local slowdown on one usually or always causes a local slowdown on the other.
I just have no idea where to go from here. I'm not even sure whether this question counts as on-topic here, because I don't know if it's a programming problem or not.

It’s not a browser issue because it’s not specific to a particular browser. Except it kind of is a browser issue because it’s specific to whichever browser I’ve been using each time.

It’s not a wordpress installation issue because the same thing happens across multiple installs on the same server. Except it kind of is a wordpress issue because it specifically happens when I am logged in and performing admin actions.

It’s not a server issue because it’s local to my device. Except it kind of is a server issue because the slowdown is specifically caused by delayed server responses.


What could be causing this / how can I solve it?

have you tried to measure what's happening server side? Tools such as query monitor can help there. You also didn't mention if you're using plugins that bundle up all the output in output buffers, run optimisations, then release it all at once e.g. autoptimise, these can cripple time to first byte and have similar symptoms to what you're seeing with server wait times. Note though that you need a specific question here, and to be able to mark an answer as the "correct" answer, open ended discussions don't fit the sites format

sounds like cron issues. try disabling wp cron in wp-config.php and see if it fixed or not.

@TomJNowell I've edited to clarify the specific question (presumably there is a single correct answer as to what's causing this issue!). I'm not using any optimisation plugins, and anyway as I noted the issue is unaffected by disabling all plugins. I'll look into query monitor, thanks.
